# How to combine custiom defined variables and display them as records of a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm a beginner in plpgsql and working on a project which requires me to write a function that returns two variables in the form of 2 columns (res,Result). I've done a quite a bit of searching but didn't find answer for the same. The reference to my code is below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION propID(character varying) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $val$
DECLARE
    t_row record;
    res BOOLEAN;
    result character varying;
    value record;
BEGIN
   FOR t_row IN SELECT property_id FROM property_table WHERE ward_id::TEXT = $1  LOOP

    RAISE NOTICE 'Analyzing %', t_row;

    res := false; -- here i'm going to replace this value with a function whos return type is boolean in future
    result := t_row.property_id;

    return next result;  --here i want to return 2 variables (res,result) in the form of two columns (id,value) 

  END LOOP;

END;
$val$
language plpgsql;
```

Any help on the above query would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `property_id` and `ward_id` are integers you can achieve your goal in a simple query like this:

```
select some_function_returning_boolean(property_id), property_id
from property_table
where ward_id = 1; -- input parameter
```

If you absolutely need a function, it can be an SQL function like

```
create or replace function prop_id(integer) 
returns table (res boolean, id int) language sql
as $$
    select some_function_returning_boolean(property_id), property_id
    from property_table
    where ward_id = $1
$$;
```

In a plpgsql function you should use `return query`:

```
create or replace function prop_id(integer) 
returns table (res boolean, id int) language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query
    select some_function_returning_boolean(property_id), property_id
    from property_table
    where ward_id = $1;
end
$$;
```

Comment: @S.Sho - note that `SELECT` is a natural way to perform loops in SQL, usually simpler and more performant than an explicit loop with variables.